# Get random point inside a webelement

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I get a random point inside the element?

I want to perform random clicks inside the element.

- i am capturing element location using `.Location`
- i am capturing element size using `.Size`

but i am stuck...

i just need to generate a random number between Location and size?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndX = rnd.Next(location.X, size_Element.Width);
int rndY = rnd.Next(location.Y, size_Element.Height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can create

- `x1=location.X`    until    `xn=location.X+size_Element.Width-1`
- `y1=location.Y`    until    `yn=location.Y+size_Element.Height-1`

Code wise, you just need to create random number between 0 to (width-1) and add to point x, and random number between 0 to (height-1) and add to point y.

Always have random instantiated once so that it can indeed generate random numbers, therefore make it static and put it outside the method:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
```

then in your method

```
int rndx = location.X + random.Next(size_Element.Width); // no need to -1, because it does not include size_Element.Width
int rndy = location.Y + random.Next(size_Element.Height); // no need to -1, because it does not include size_Element.Width
```